# Push to git from web application

Tags: git, server, vuejs2

I am trying to develop a web application that enables editing source code of existing project in a git repository i need to perform all operation of git from the web application am using [Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) as front end.

Which language is best for these operation ,then how perform it?

Comment: You can call the git executable practically in the same way with any server side language (exec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Java on server + [JGit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JGit/article.html).
Avoid to use any Git frameworks on client side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any framework in front end. In the backend you can write api endpoints for interacting with the git repository hosted on the server machine. In backend you can Python Django framework(If this project has to be pushed to production) or Python flask framework (If its hobby project). Good luck.